# Hyperledger Network Roles

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I'm going through the documentation on Hyperledger Fabric, and there's a portion in the introduction that writes:

"Hyperledger Fabric assigns network roles by node type. To provide concurrency and parallelism to the network, transaction execution is separated from transaction ordering and commitment. *Executing transactions prior to ordering them enables each peer node to process multiple transactions simultaneously.*"

Maybe this is some fundamental misunderstanding on my part about the structure of the network and the different functions and mechanics of nodes, but how can one execute a transaction **prior** to ordering one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a Hyperledger Fabric network, transactions start out with client applications sending transaction proposals, or, in other words, proposing a transaction to endorsing peers.

Each endorsing peer simulates the proposed transaction, without updating the ledger. The endorsing peers will capture the set of Read and Written data, called RW Sets.

These RW sets are then signed by the endorsing peer, and returned to the client application to be used in future steps of the transaction flow. Endorsing peers must hold smart contracts in order to simulate the transaction proposals.

The application then submits the endorsed transaction and the RW sets to the ordering service. Ordering happens across the network, in parallel with endorsed transactions and RW sets submitted by other applications.

The ordering service takes the endorsed transactions and RW sets, orders this information into a block, and delivers the block to all committing peers.

The committing peer validates the transaction by checking to make sure that the RW sets still match the current world state.

Committing peers are responsible for adding blocks of transactions to the shared ledger and updating the world state.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it answers more comprehensively the network flow misunderstandings at the heart of this question.

Comment: In the process between endorsing peer responding to transaction proposals( assume N) from client to sending the R/W set to orderer what if there is another transaction proposal( Assume M) being proposed which has changes for the values in 'N' ? how is this handled, because in this case the version of commit will be different for N and M, and hence M will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have the roles that there are in Hyperledger Fabric:

- Endorser Peers: they receive a transaction. Then, they execute the transaction against the Smart Contrat and they sign the result. They send the transaction signed to the peer that has sent it.
- Committer Peers: the Peers get the Blocks (with the validates transactions) and commit them to its ledger.
- Orderes: nodes that sort the transactions and generate the blocks.

I take this info from an answer that I write for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008450/who-is-a-validating-peer/47058668#47058668).